# I have an error of array_pop(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given using PHP 8.2.7 and laravel 10.13.5

Tags: php, laravel

I am learning laravel and php from laracasts tutorials. In [episode 35](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch/episodes/35) i have an error happen. It is an array error .
Error Message shown on the browser is given below:

> TypeError array_pop(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given

The error is caused by this line

```
{{ isset($currentCategory) ? ucwords($currentCategory -> name) : 'Categories' }}
```

The code is given below

My C:\Users\Admin\app-first\resources\views_posts-header.blade.php

```
<header class="max-w-xl mx-auto mt-20 text-center">
        <h1 class="text-4xl">
            Latest <span class="text-blue-500">Laravel From Scratch</span> News
        </h1>

        <h2 class="inline-flex mt-2">By Lary Laracore <img src="./images/lary-head.svg" alt="Head of Lary the mascot"></h2>

        <p class="text-sm mt-14">
            Another year. Another update. We're refreshing the popular Laravel series with new content.
            I'm going to keep you guys up to speed with what's going on!
        </p>

        <div class="space-y-2 lg:space-y-0 lg:space-x-4 mt-8">

            <!--  Category -->
            <div class="relative lg:inline-flex bg-gray-100 rounded-xl">      
                <x-dropdown>
                    <x-slot name ="trigger"  > 
                        <button class="py-2 pl-3 pr-9 text-sm font-semibold w-full lg:w-32 text-left flex lg:inline-flex">
                            {{ isset($currentCategory) ? ucwords($currentCategory -> name) : 'Categories' }}
                            <svg class="transform -rotate-90 absolute pointer-events-none" style="right: 12px;" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22">
                                <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                                    <path stroke="#000" stroke-opacity=".012" stroke-width=".5" d="M21 1v20.16H.84V1z">
                                    </path>
                                    <path fill="#222" d="M13.854 7.224l-3.847 3.856 3.847 3.856-1.184 1.184-5.04-5.04 5.04-5.04z"></path>
                                </g>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </x-slot>

                                <a href="/" class="block text-left px-3 text-sm leading-6 hover:bg-blue-500 focus:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white focus:text-white ">
                                All
                                </a>

                                @foreach ($categories as $category )
                                    <a href="/categories/{{ $category -> slug }}" 
                                    class=" 
                                    block text-left px-3 text-sm leading-6 
                                    hover:bg-blue-500 focus:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white focus:text-white 
                                    {{ isset($currentCategory) && $currentCategory -> is( $category )  ? 'bg-blue-500 text-white' : '' }}
                                    " >
                                    {{ ucwords( $category -> name ) }}
                                    </a>
                                @endforeach
                </x-dropdown>
            </div>

            <!-- Other Filters -->
            <div class="relative flex lg:inline-flex items-center bg-gray-100 rounded-xl">
                <select class="flex-1 appearance-none bg-transparent py-2 pl-3 pr-9 text-sm font-semibold">
                    <option value="category" disabled selected>Other Filters
                    </option>
                    <option value="foo">Foo
                    </option>
                    <option value="bar">Bar
                    </option>
                </select>

                <svg class="transform -rotate-90 absolute pointer-events-none" style="right: 12px;" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22">
                    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                        <path stroke="#000" stroke-opacity=".012" stroke-width=".5" d="M21 1v20.16H.84V1z">
                        </path>
                        <path fill="#222" d="M13.854 7.224l-3.847 3.856 3.847 3.856-1.184 1.184-5.04-5.04 5.04-5.04z"></path>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </div>

            <!-- Search -->
            <div class="relative flex lg:inline-flex items-center bg-gray-100 rounded-xl px-3 py-2">
                <form method="GET" action="#">
                    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Find something" class="bg-transparent placeholder-black font-semibold text-sm">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

**C:\Users\Admin\app-first\resources\views\components\dropdown.blade.php**

```
@props(['trigger']) 

<div x-data="{ show: false}" @click.away="show=false"> 
{{-- Trigger --}} 
<div @click = "show =! show "> 
{{ $trigger }} 
</div> 
{{-- Links --}} 
<div x-show="show" class="py-2 absolute bg-gray-100 mt-2 rounded-xl w-full z-50" style="display: none"> 
{{ $slot }} 
</div> 
</div>
```

**Routes\web.php**

```
Route::get('categories/{category:slug}', function(Category $category){ return view('posts', [ 
'posts' => $category->posts, 
'currentCategory' => $category,
'categories' => Category::all(), 
]);
```

How I can fix this error?

Comment: Can you share what your blade component looks like, at least the part that will go into the `x-slot name="trigger" `

Comment: @props(['trigger'])
<div x-data="{ show: false}" @click.away="show=false">
    {{-- Trigger --}}
             <div @click = "show =! show ">  
             {{ $trigger }}
            </div>
    {{-- Links --}}
    <div x-show="show" class="py-2 absolute bg-gray-100 mt-2 rounded-xl w-full z-50" style="display: none">
         {{ $slot }}
    </div>

</div>

Comment: You need to [edit] your question please when you have an update. Code in comments is hard to read. Thankyou

Comment: Route::get('categories/{category:slug}', function(Category $category){

    return  view('posts', [
        'posts' => $category->posts,
        'currentCategory' => $category,
        'categories' => Category::all(),

    ]);

Comment: You render `{{ $trigger }}`. Are you sure that's correct? That will escape all HTML markup

Comment: Again... **edit your question**. Do not add code to the comments! Everything should be in one place, in the main post

Comment: I have added the code to the question post now it is clear. Also, it is the laracasts episode 35.

Comment: @apokryfos
  code is added now you can see

Comment: @ADyson
 What is the solution to this error?

Comment: Where are you getting this syntax from? You use `<x-slot name="trigger">` but normally it should be `<x-slot:trigger>` then you use `@props([ 'trigger' ])` to indicate `trigger` is actually a data attribute (i.e. not a slot) then you render `{{ $trigger }}` which would also escape the markup if it were to actually work. Try doing (a) remove `@props` from your component, (b) change the slot to `<x-slot:trigger>` and (c) use `{!! $trigger  !!}` in your component

Comment: @apokryfos Thank You So much For Your help. Trying Your Steps Finally worked for Me. I  have continued my laracasts episodes. I have less knowledge of laravel and PHP, and it is my first time learning. So Your steps and method are correct for me. Thank You So Much apokryfos

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this error, you must remove spaces from name attribute

before:

```
<x-slot name ="trigger"  >
```

after:

```
<x-slot name="trigger">
```

Answer (score -2):

array_pop accept array as parameter and you passed null so you received this error, to resolve this pass array instead null

```
    $a=array("1","2","3");
    array_pop($a);
    print_r($a);
```